# How to save to JSON File in NodeJS Google Play Scraper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, google-play

I am trying to work with Google Play Scraper and I need a full list fo all appIds written with NodeJS. My problem is it only gives output of console.log. What I need is to save this to JSON, then transform to CSV. Do you have any idea how to save this to JSON? I am new to NodeJS.

```
    var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
    var fs = require('fs');

    gplay.list({
        category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
        collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
       num: 2
      })
      .then(function(apps){
        fs.writeFileSync('myjsonfile.json', console.log);
      })
      .catch(function(e){
        console.log('There was an error fetching the list!');
      });
```

Comment: `.then(function(apps){ fs.writeFileSync('myjsonfile.json', JSON.stringify(apps)); })`

Answer (score -1):

```
// Import file system module

const fs = require('fs');


const writeToFile = (fileName) => (data) => {
  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('complete');
    }
  );
}


gplay.list({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    num: 2
  })
  .then(writeToFile('your-file-name.json'), console.error);
```

Comment: Please give some context to your answer and don't just post code.